# Design pattern for a dynamic CRUD application that generates user definable documents?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, crud, dynamically-generated

I'm building a C# desktop application for the management of HR decisions (e.g., the termination of a contract, the approval of a requested leave,...). 
These decisions are to yield several Office documents (e.g., contracts, lists...).

The end user must be able to:

- define new types of decisions,
- define the content of the corresponding documents (by which i mean, define the boilerplate text, and the positions where data from a field needs to be inserted),
- change the content of the documents for a given DecisionType.

The **design i have in mind**:

The class Decision has a field decisionType.
The class DecisionType has a property **FieldsList**, which lists the names of all fields the DecisionType has, and their datatypes.

When the end user clicks a button to enter a new decision, the application **generates a user form** (i suppose WPF is more suitable for this then WinForms is, although i've never used it) that allows creation of a new decision of the chosen DecisionType. This form contains **only those controls** needed for the fields a decision of that type uses. The application adds all required databinding.

The end user manages the **content of the documents** for each DecisionType:

- the boiler plate text,
- the positions where persisted data need to be inserted.

This is saved as a string, in which the position where data from a field needs to be inserted, is indicated by a code (e.g., "/[bd]" for the field BeginDate).

The database uses a **single table** for all decisions (although most DecisionTypes won't use all fields).

But... maybe you people know a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like only one table won't help. I mean, you got to create a Person class besides the Decision one. Each Person may have one or many Decision and a Decision should be editable by another people.

Let's get an example:

1. John made a decision and save it as `Decision A`
2. Paul agrees with `Decision A` but would like to have some other input at it.

I guess you can see where this is going.
Regarding technologies, I would definitely use WPF - although its learning curve is steeper, once you got it you can do anything, practically. WPF also suggest a MVVM approach, which will greatly improve your time with Data Binding. 
As for Database, I recommend Entityframework. Its Code First scheme is very easy to understand and you'll find a lot of info around.

Some useful links:
[www.wpftutorial.net -  Very basic, introductory WPF info, great for starters](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

[CodeProject - MVVM Example for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute)

[Julie Lerman's Entity Framework website - She's one of the best at it!](http://learnentityframework.com/)

Don't give up and good luck.

Comment: It seems i need to clarify 2 things here:
- i plan on using a single table for the Decisions, as opposed to building an inheritance hierarchy of DecisionTypes, and storing Decisions of a given type in a separate table. That doesn't mean i won't add tables for e.g. Employee records. 
- the decisions are the employer's decisions, not the employees'. Each decision does concern a given employee though.

Thanks for your suggestions regarding EF and WPF, and the links you posted :)